# How to format the column in column chart in Microsoft Word 2007 or 2010

Tags: printing, charts, ms-word

I'm using column chart in Microsoft Word 2010. It differentiates columns by its color. The problem comes when I have to print that page out, but not in color. So all columns are the same, all in black.

So, can I change the column format so as to differentiate them even in black only? For example, one column has vertical stripes, another has horizontal stripe,...

If Microsoft Word can't do that, please recommend me another tool to achieve it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on a column in your chart.

Click **Format Data Series** > Select the **FIll** tab > Select **Pattern Fill**

Choose a pattern you like.